# print hour & minutes in french style

Tags: babel, siunitx, datetime, french

I'm using `babel`, `datetime` & `siunitx` but I don't see an automatic way to mark and to write time in the french style. It's possible with plain hour with `datetime`: `SI{18}{\hour}` -> `18 h`. But for hours & minutes, I don't if exists something better than `14~h~27` ->  `14 h 27`. An idea ?

Comment: For scientific use, I'd expect to see either `\SI{14.45}{\hour}` or `SI{867}{\minute}` (assuming you  really need that accuracy): mixing units doesn't really work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of the french style but you can make your own style with `datetime`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newtimeformat{frenchtime}{%
\twodigit{\THEHOUR}\ h\ %
\twodigit{\THEMINUTE}\ min}

\settimeformat{frenchtime}

\begin{document}

Et  maintenant il est exactement  \formattime{13}{50}{45}.


Ce document a été généré à \currenttime.  


\end{document}
```

This MWE should produce a  ouput like:

> Et  maintenant il est exactement  13 h 50 min.
>
> Ce document a été généré à 13 h 50 min.

Comment: Thanks, it works. We can use in french 13 h 50 min or 13 h 50 with `…\twodigit{\THEMINUTE}}`. Now, my question is, how to print 9 h 05 & not 09 h 05 ? I imagine without `\twodigit`… I try

Comment: Ok, it works. I edit your answer in this way. Last question, impossible to write only two arguments `formattime{}{}` instead of `formattime{}{}{}` ?

Comment: I propose for using in french texts this form without `\twodigit` hour & without `\min`units : `\newtimeformat{frenchtime}{{\THEHOUR}\ h\ \twodigit{\THEMINUTE}}`

Comment: @Zouib, the 3 arguments are mandatory, but you always can make your own command with 2 arguments only:  `\newcommand\lheure[2]{\formattime{#1}{#2}{00}}`